# Redux Saga, why do I receive an error when unit testing a saga from a file containing a fat arrow function?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have encountered the following scenario when trying to test a saga from redux saga.

Some package information:

I use `redux-saga@0.15.6`, `redux@3.7.2` with `node v9.5.0` and `npm 5.6.0`.

I have the following structure:

```
sagas
    index.js
    index.spec.js
```

Inside `index.js`, I define my sagas. A basic idea of what I have there is this:

```
function doSomething() {
  /* Some code */
}

function* notExportedSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(SOME_ACTION, doSomething)
}

export function* exportedSaga(action) {
  yield put({ type: OTHER_ACTION, payload: somePayload })
}
```

In `index.spec.js`, I want to test my sagas. I have a `import` at the top of my file:

```
import { exportedSaga } from './index'
```

With the structure and code I described, this works just fine. However, if I change `doSomething` from being defined like it is to a fat arrow function:

```
const doSomething = () => {
  /* Some code */
}
```

What will happen is, when running the unit tests, I will get this error:

```
console.error node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/utils.js:240
  uncaught at rootSaga
   at rootSaga
   at rootSaga
   ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined
```

Do you know why this is happening?

---

I have open a [issue](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1357) , because I don't know if this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Function declarations** like

```
function doSomething() { }
```

are being **hoisted** to the top

**Function expressions** like

```
const doSomething = () => { }
```

are **not** being hoisted

That's why you're getting `doSomething is not defined` - both `notExportedSaga` and `exportedSaga` functions are being hoisted to the top while the expression function `const doSomething = () => { }` is not and it is undefined on your generator functions invocations.

Here's a cool article about `hoisting` if you want to know more :) https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript